# Executing PhantomJS From Inside Jar

Tags: java, phantomjs, windows-8.1

I'm using [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/download.html) to do headless testing of a website. Since the `exe` will be bundled inside the `jar` file I decided to read it and write it to a temporary file so that I can access it normally via absolute path.

Here's code for converting an `InputStream` into a `String` referring to the new temporary file:

```
public String getFilePath(InputStream inputStream, String fileName)
        throws IOException
{
    String fileContents = readFileToString(inputStream);
    File file = createTemporaryFile(fileName);
    String filePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
    writeStringToFile(fileContents, filePath);

    return file.getAbsolutePath();
}

private void writeStringToFile(String text, String filePath)
        throws FileNotFoundException
{
    PrintWriter fileWriter = new PrintWriter(filePath);

    fileWriter.print(text);
    fileWriter.close();
}

private File createTemporaryFile(String fileName)
{
    String tempoaryFileDirectory = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
    File temporaryFile = new File(tempoaryFileDirectory + File.separator
            + fileName);

    return temporaryFile;
}

private String readFileToString(InputStream inputStream)
        throws UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException
{
    StringBuilder inputStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));

    String line;
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        inputStringBuilder.append(line);
        inputStringBuilder.append(System.lineSeparator());
    }

    String fileContents = inputStringBuilder.toString();

    return fileContents;
}
```

This works but when I'm trying to launch PhantomJS it'll give me an `ExecuteException`:

```
SERVERE: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Execution failed (Exit value: -559038737. Caused by java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Users\%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp\phantomjs.exe" (in directory "."): CreateProcess error=216, the version of %1 is not compatible with this Windows version. Check the system information of your computer and talk to the distributor of this software)
```

If I don't try to read `PhantomJS` out of the `jar` hence using a relative path it works fine. The question is how I can read and execute `PhantomJS` from within a jar file or at least get the workaround with reading and writing a new (temporary) file to work.

Comment: Why is the PhantomJS exe in the jar file in the first place?

Comment: @ArtjomB.
So that users don't need to care about webdriver executables

Comment: You're reading phantomjs.exe into a String?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't execute a JAR entry, because a JAR is a zip file and operating systems don't support running executables from inside a zip file. They could in principle, but it would boil down to "copy the exe out of the zip and then run it".

The exe is getting corrupted because you're storing it in a String. Strings aren't binary data, they're UTF-16, which is why you can't read straight from an InputStream into a String--encoding conversion is required. Your code is reading the exe as UTF-8, converting it to UTF-16, then writing it back out with the default character set. Even if the default character set happens to be UTF-8 on your machine, this will result in mangled data because an exe isn't valid UTF-8.

Try this on for size. Java 7 introduced NIO.2, which (among other things), has a lot of convenience methods for common file operations. Including putting an InputStream into a file! I'm also using the temp file API, which will prevent collisions if multiple instances of your app are run at the same time.

```
public String getFilePath(InputStream inputStream, String prefix, String suffix)
        throws IOException
{
    java.nio.file.Path p = java.nio.file.Files.createTempFile(prefix, suffix);
    p.toFile().deleteOnExit();
    java.nio.file.Files.copy(inputStream, p, java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    return p.toAbsolutePath().toString();
}
```